# Figure comparing path length and density (figure 3a) in paper "Isolation-based Anomaly Detection" by Liu, Ting and Zhou

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

In the paper *[Isolation-based Anomaly Detection](https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/tkdd11.pdf)* by *Liu*, *Ting* and *Zhou*, figure 3a compares the density and path length for a cluster of anomalies. Figure 3a along with the sub-text has been provided as image below (figure 3b has not been provided).

[image]
[image]

I have confusion regarding the symbols and the interpretation of this figure. My understanding from the sub-text (and the paper) is that -

1. "x" marks indicate the position of data points along the x-axis. There might be multiple x-marks overlapping at a particular position.
2. The "x" mark on the left denotes a dense cluster of 20 anomalous data points on the extreme left. The normal points form a spread-out cluster (following gaussian distribution) on the right.
3. There are probably 20 diamond marks at the position of the anomalous cluster, ranging from a density value (right y-axis scale) of ~400 to ~3200. What do these diamond marks denote? Do they stand for  the density around each data point? If yes, shouldn't the 20 data points have nearly same density, given they are all clustered together at same position; why the large spread of density value over such a large range along the right-side y-axis, for these 20 points?